# The page you were looking for doesn't exist.(Heroku)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making Rails application, 
I did `git push heroku master`, but I got the error "The page you were looking for doesn't exist".

when checked `heroku logs --tail`,

```
2013-10-21T09:35:55.847956+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2013-10-21T09:35:55.847645+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2013-10-21T09:36:03.189191+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -p 13465`
2013-10-21T09:36:04.333654+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2013-10-21T09:36:04.333654+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 2.6.0, codename: Pantsuit Party
2013-10-21T09:36:04.333654+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
2013-10-21T09:36:04.333654+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2013-10-21T09:36:06.831825+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:13465
2013-10-21T09:36:06.832075+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2013-10-21T09:36:07.101486+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-10-21T09:36:10.072764+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=tweet-code.herokuapp.com fwd="106.188.96.138" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=151ms status=200 bytes=66
2013-10-21T09:36:10.554305+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/500.html host=tweet-code.herokuapp.com fwd="106.188.96.138" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=1351
```

It's working in development. The database.yml is like this.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: tweetcode_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: tweetcode_test
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: 
  host: 
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
```

I did `heroku run rake db:migrate`, it's fine.

When I `git push heroku master` , I got `Running: rake assets:precompile
       Asset precompilation completed`, so it's not about asset precompilation.

Is there any point I need check to solve this problem?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does it work in development?

Comment: Also, it could be a problem with your database setup -> can you send your database.yml (without credentials obv) ?

Comment: please post detail heroku logs.